# localstorageを使って、テーマカラーを取得しテーマカラーを保存しておく方法

Tags: javascript, jquery

ボタンをクリックすることで、styleSheetを変更し、テーマカラー(背景色)を変えるように設定しました。

ここまでの設定はできたのですが、
localStorageを使って、変更したテーマカラー保存した状態にしたいのですが、
localStorageをどのように設定したらよいのかがわかりません。。

localStorageを使用するのが初めてで、
保存するときは、`localStorage.setItem('Key', '保存する値');`などの情報があるのですが、
これをどう扱っていけばよいのかがわかりません。。

情報に不足部分があるかもしれませんが、ご教授いただけますと大変助かります。

```js
//テーマカラーの切り替え
function setHref($href) {
  var $elementReference = document.getElementById("s_theme");
  $elementReference.href = $href;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalmode.css" id="s_theme">
  
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button onclick="setHref('normalmode.css');" class="normalmode"></button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button onclick="setHref('darkmode.css');" class="darkmode"></button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button onclick="setHref('lightmode.css');" class="lightmode"></button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setHref()`内で `localStorage.setItem(固定のキー文字列, $href)`して、ページロード時に`getItem(固定のキー文字列)`が`null`でない場合は`setHref()`を呼んでしまえばよいでしょう。

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalmode.css" id="s_theme">
<script>
function setHref($href) {
  var $elementReference = document.getElementById("s_theme");
  $elementReference.href = $href;
  localStorage.setItem('theme_style', $href);
}

// このコードは文書ロード時に実行される前提
let style = localStorage.getItem('theme_style');
if (style !== null) {
  setHref(style);
}
</script>
```

Comment: お教えいただきましたもので、テーマを切り替えたあと、そのままの状態を保存することができるようになりました。`style !== null`という書き方をするということも大変勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0):

setHrefでlocalStorageに保存。

```
  function setHref($href) {
    var $elementReference = document.getElementById("s_theme");
    $elementReference.href = $href;
    localStorage.setItem('key', $href); //ここで保存
  }
```

bodyのonload時などでlocalStorageから読みだして下記のような関数でセットします。

```
function getHref() {
  var $elementReference = document.getElementById("s_theme");
  $elementReference.href = localStorage.getItem('key');
}
```

Comment: お教えいただきありがとうございます。お教えいただきました記述で試したところ、どうもうまく行かなかったのですが、「bodyのonload時などでlocalStorageから読みだして」とありますが、他にもなにか記述が必要なのでしょうか？今後の参考までにも教えていただけますと大変助かります。

Comment: 上記の内容ですと <body onload="getHref()"> とすれば可能ですよ。やり方は色々あるのでお試しください。

Comment: 詳細を教えていただきありがとうございます。` <body onload="getHref()"> `とすることで実行することができました。色々なやり方があるということをお教えいただき大変勉強になります。ありがとうございました。

Comment: いえいえ、ご丁寧にお聞きくださいましてありがとうございます。